# Can we remove or hide path elements from swagger documentation?

Tags: java, swagger, jax-rs, openapi

My public API is served by my main web application but on a different domain. So that the paths don't conflict with my normal webapp paths, the public API endpoints have a hidden prefix. That is, when someone visits `https://api.example.com/foo` they are internally forwarded to `/publicApi/foo`; requests to `https://www.example.com/foo` are processed normally.

Of course this means the JAX-RS classes for my API are all annotated like this:

```
@Path("/publicApi")
public class PublicApiFooResource {
    @Path("/foo")
    public Foo getFoo() {...}
}
```

Using `swagger-jaxrs2` (v2.2.7), this generates an openapi document that includes `/publicApi`:

```
paths: {
    /publicApi/foo: {
        get: { ... } etc
```

How can I get swagger-jaxrs2 to ignore the hidden leading part of the path? The path, from the world's perspective, is `/foo`; the internal forward shouldn't leak into the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a mediocre solution to what seems like a common problem, but it does work. Enable this `filterClass` in the swagger config:

```
package com.example;

import io.swagger.v3.core.filter.AbstractSpecFilter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.PathItem;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Paths;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Optional;

public class PathSpecFilter extends AbstractSpecFilter {
    private static final String PUBLIC_PATH = "/thePublicApiPrefix";

    @Override
    public Optional<OpenAPI> filterOpenAPI(final OpenAPI openAPI, final Map<String, List<String>> params, final Map<String, String> cookies, final Map<String, List<String>> headers) {
        final Optional<OpenAPI> opt = super.filterOpenAPI(openAPI, params, cookies, headers);
        return opt.map(openapi -> {
            openapi.setPaths(fix(openapi.getPaths()));
            return openapi;
        });
    }

    private Paths fix(final Paths paths) {
        final Paths next = new Paths();

        for (final Entry<String, PathItem> entry : paths.entrySet()) {
            final String key = entry.getKey().startsWith(PUBLIC_PATH)
                    ? entry.getKey().substring(PUBLIC_PATH.length())
                    : entry.getKey();
            next.put(key, entry.getValue());
        }

        return next;
    }
}
```